# Unable to use Font Awesome in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, visual-studio-code, font-awesome

Following [official docs](https://fontawesome.com/get-started/advanced-options). After running:

```
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

and:

```
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid
```

trying to (TypeScript):

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid';
...
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} />
```

getting:

[image]

However `@types/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome` is a wrong name and doesn't exist. Tried to sintall https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-fontawesome without luck.

Visual Studio Code. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not simply just link it in the index.html file no need for npm?

Comment: Because it gives you tools to optimize the bundle - by not including tons of icons you are NOT going to use.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: paste your package.json  contents and package.lock resolution for this library please

Comment: I tried the above code without typescript and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

To use `fontawesome`with react use [react-fontawesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome)

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome
npm i --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid
```

First install all the above packages. Then use as follows.

```
import React from 'react'

import FontAwesomeIcon from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import faCoffee from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid/faCoffee'

class Fonte extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee}/>
    )
  }
}

export default Fonte;
```

The issue, I believe is due to `import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';` this in your code.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround until there is typescript support, this is what we did:

```
declare module '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro';
declare module '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
```

This is added to our global ts definition file: `global.d.ts` inside src path.

EDIT: For us, the second line isn't requuired in TS., maybe your version of react-fontawesome is old. Ours is `"^0.1.14"`